# How to divide the text into two columns by matching text using SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with a column `Note / Reason` - like this:

```
Note / Reason
test
test2
test  REASON:ANOTHER PROVIDER
this is a test  REASON:NO FITTER
```

I want to divide the text like below into note and reason like below reason with start with reason and other text will be note

```
Note                        Reason
---------------------------------------------------
test
test2'
test                        REASON:ANOTHER PROVIDER
this is a test              REASON:NO FITTER
```

Comment: Hint: `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT` and `STUFF`

Comment: i want to using select query? if you give sample example it will help more. @Larnu

Comment: Those are functions that can be used in a SELECT clause. Have you tried using them? Checking their documentation?

Comment: Yuck.  I'd do this transformation outside of SQL Server, then reimport a two column CSV flat file.

Comment: Please can you post your answer. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: If you can show us your attempts, and explain why they didn't work, @mohdmazharkhan , that'll greatly help us help you.

Comment: okay sir I check that hint thanks you lot. @Larnu

Comment: The biggest issue here is that you have violated 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. Hopefully part of your project is fixing the table once you figure out how to split the data apart.

Comment: Yes sir you are correct and this was done 10 years back, i am working for support @SeanLange

Comment: do you have an idea about this answer? @SeanLange

Comment: hi i am not getting combined example CHARINDEX, LEFT and STUFF. @Larnu

Comment: You may well *not* find one, @mohdmazharkhan , but you'll find plenty of documentation on how to use each of them; it's up to you to combine then. Again, if you show your attempt(s) and explain why they didn't work, that'll greatly help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Sean's sample data, as I mentioned in the comments, use `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT` and `STUFF`:

```sql
SELECT LEFT(NoteReason,CHARINDEX('REASON:',NoteReason + 'REASON:')-1) AS Note,
       STUFF(NoteReason,1,CHARINDEX('REASON:',NoteReason)-1,'') AS Reason
FROM @NoteReason;
```

Considering you have extra white space, you may also want to wrap the expressions in a `TRIM`.

Comment: Just curious why this would be better. It is a bit less code for sure but otherwise it is pretty much the same thing I was doing.

Comment: I don't think anyone has said this is "better", @SeanLange .

Comment: haha true. A different way to skin the same cat for sure. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you provided sample data in a consumable format. That way it is easy for others to use and it is also more precise so others aren't guessing or making assumptions about your tables and sample data. Given the sparse information in your question something like this should be somewhat close.

```
declare @NoteReason table (NoteReason varchar(100))
insert @NoteReason values
('test')
, ('test2')
, ('test  REASON:ANOTHER PROVIDER')
, ('this is a test  REASON:NO FITTER')

select Note = case when charindex('REASON', n.NoteReason) = 0 then n.NoteReason
        else left(n.NoteReason, charindex('REASON', n.NoteReason) - 1)
        end
    , Reason = case when charindex('REASON', n.NoteReason) > 0 then substring(n.NoteReason, charindex('REASON', n.NoteReason), len(n.NoteReason)) else '' end
from @NoteReason n
```